# Automatically extracting functions names and parameters from ABI JSON file

Tags: solidity, contract-development, javascript, abi

I have done some work on captioned subject. For example, I can extract all getter functions (and some constructors as well) of all given smart contracts (in abi json file format). Then i can call (extracted) function of respective contract one by one after deploying (that) contracts on ganache.  Now i am facing problem that how to extract setter functions (which take some inputs of 1, 2, 3 or more arguments) name alongwith their parameter's type/name. So that i could caller such setter function with some valid random values.

```
function abiExpr()
{
for(i=0; i<sources.length; i++){ // here sources has my contracts in json files

  if(!getterFunctionsObject[i])
    getterFunctionsObject[i] = [] // making array to store getter function of each contract... I think , its not a good way ... but it working...

  if(!constrObject[i])
    constrObject[i] = [] // making array to store constructor of each contract

  if(!setterFunctionsObject[i])
  setterFunctionsObject[i] = [] //making array to store setter function of each contract

  if(!settersParameters[i])
  settersParameters[i] = []
  if(!settersParameters[i][i])
  settersParameters[i][i] = [] // HERE I AM STUCK, and confused how to achiev..... want to make array to store every parameter of each setter for each contract ... * 

  for (let item of sources[i].abi) {

    if (item.type === "constructor") /// its OK for some constructor
    {
      constrObject[i].push(item.inputs)

    }

    if (item.type === "function") // its OK 100 % 
    {
      if((item.inputs).length ==0 && item.stateMutability==='view')
     getterFunctionsObject[i].push(item.name)
    }

    if (item.type === "function") /// its not working .. HOW to achieve ...
    {
      if((item.inputs).length>0)
          {

            for(t=0 ; t<(item.inputs).length; t++)
            {
              if ((item.inputs[t].name).length>0)
              {
                setterFunctionsObject[i].push(item.name)
                settersParameters[i][t].push(item.inputs[t].name)
              }
            }
          }
    }
}
}
}
```

In order to summarize, how to store **each** parameter of **each** setter function of **each** contract. Is there any ABI APIs for my above mentioned tasks? If possible, also need some better coding approach, as i think above code is not good practice.

NOTE: For setter function, I means which take some parameters , and getter function means which just return some output.

Answer (score 0):

Tools exist to convert the ABI into a Solidity [interface](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.25/contracts.html#interfaces), which contains all of the function names.

- In Python - [abi2solc](https://github.com/iamdefinitelyahuman/abi2solc)
- In Javascript - [abi2solidity](https://github.com/maxme/abi2solidity)

The data in an ABI is generic enough that interfaces can be generated to work with `^0.5.0` or `^0.4.22`, or earlier if tuple types aren't used.

Comment: i think, i could not explained well.. actually i have also .sol files .. but i need to deploy, and then call their function automatically without looking into .sol file...